# Angular 5 update template after event

Tags: angular, angular-components, ngfor, angular-template

This is my third post on angular. 
I want to display a list of type candidates: Candidate[]. 
I am currently displaying it in the view using an *ngFor like this:

```
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let candidate of candidates">
            {{ candidate.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
```

However, i need to filter the candidates to fit the user search with a function :

```
  filterResults(queryString): void {
    this.candidatesService.filterCandidates(queryString).subscribe(candidates => this.filteredCandidates = candidates);
    this.filteredCandidates = this.filteredCandidates.filter(candidate => candidate.name == queryString);
  }
```

The problem is, the function is triggered on keyup of an input box. So, the filtered candidates array value is changing based on input.

**Does anybody know how do i update the template view too, to only display the newly only the results in the updated array ?**

Comment: Replace `candidates` by `filteredCandidates`?

Comment: @spectacularbob no, you really shouldn't: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: Thanks for advice. I actually changed from candidates to filteredCandidates and it is the same thing. I think the problem is the *ngFor doesn't update if the variable is changed.
I also tried with async pipe, but throws an error.

Comment: It does. The bug is in your code, not in angular. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x54dad?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: why don't you use a `temp[]` array -@Gabriel

Comment: I used something like that, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

make temp in `*ngFor` and store your candidates in `temp[]` that used whenever at not searching condition and in keyup process processing get the `this.filteredCandidates`  and push it into the `temp[]` and display.

Comment: I actually used something like that. The problem was solved. I have an array with all the candidates and filter them after.